# ADT eclipse xml layout text editor - often broken until file closed and reopened

Tags: eclipse, android

I'm new to Eclipse and ADT but have set up my environment on two different machines, and both are displaying the same oddities (both are Windows 7 64 bit).

When changing tabs between the graphical layout and the main.xml views, the lines of code in the main.xml view will start disappearing or moving around. It's hard to display this without a video or animated gif, but I'll attempt with these screenshots:

Note that all I've done is highlight a block of text, and suddenly all these artifacts shwo up. It makes development a bit less than pleasant.

Any thoughts? Please Help me to solve this problem.

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

Comment: Does minimizing and restoring the window help?  What about resizing it?  I've noticed this behaviour on occasion, but not consistently...

Comment: @Breakthrough What do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been solved in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030727/moving-and-vanishing-lines-of-code-trouble-with-eclipses-xml-editor). Seems that the bug has been fixed in the last release of ADT.